# How can it grow the chest by different variation of push-ups

Tags: workout

I have seen a lot video in internet,by doing push-ups chest can become more bigger.Which workouts could give grow results on chest area,by different push-ups?

Answer (score 1):

It's all about straining the muscles and recovery.

I do sets of 25 pushups, but with three rests of about 20 sec within each set.  Those micro-rests are important for muscle recovery (stuff like oxygen, glycogen, lactate).  In a training session I do 100 to 150 pushups in sets of 25, mixed in with other (mostly aerobic) exercise.

Try that for 6 weeks and you should see a definite improvement.

Answer (score 0):

For chest hypertrophy usual recommendation is weight lifting, not push-ups. That is because there is very little overload when you do push-ups, you basically training endurance at the point of 100s of pushups.

Weightlifting (exercises such as bench press with barbell/dumbbells, flies with dumbbells) allow you to more efficiently utilize your time and see increase in muscle mass faster.

Regardless of what workout you choose, you should start tracking your progress. [Use measuring tape](https://www.artofmanliness.com/articles/measuring-the-man-how-to-measure-yourself-for-clothing-plus-a-bonus-personal-sizing-card/) to know whether your workout works or not. When chest stop growing -- time to switch workout